# Q1. Why we get same stack address at each time we execute a program if we disable ASLR?

Tags: linux, aslr

I'm trying to understand memory address allocation for processes in linux. By default we have ASLR ON in linux. So it will give us different stack memory addresses each time.
But my question is why we get same address after disabling ASLR? Does Kernel save previous allocated address space for that previously executed program? or How does allocation happens?

Comment: It's a virtual address. All programs get the same one.

Comment: No, It's not happening. Same executable getting same addresses but each different executable have different even if it is compile from same program.

Comment: Please add your evidence to the question.

Comment: ahh, sorry, My bad, I thinks when I checked earlier ASLR was ON.
Can you provide some reference to read about it in more details?thanks